# openstack API python - no module named version

Tags: python, python-2.7, openstack, openstack-nova, novaclient

I'm trying to instanciate VM on openstack using the NovaClient API in python. More precisely with mq-rabbit celery tasks.

Unfortunatly I got this error :

```
from novaclient import client
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novaclient/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
import pbr.version
ImportError: No module named version
```

I already tested with a simple python file and it works, my VM was created but when I try to do this throught a celery tash I got the error above...

My version is the latest python-novaclient-6.0.2, but as our servers are in version 2 I use the version 2 API.
Here is my code in my celery task, who works when I test in python shell :

```
loader = loading.get_plugin_loader('password')
    auth = loader.load_from_options(auth_url=auth_url, username=username, password=password, project_name=tenant_name)
    sess = session.Session(auth=auth)
    nova = client.Client('2', session=sess) #API version and session
```

Comment: `pip uninstall pbr` and then `pip install pbr`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's the same error and [this one](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11517)

Basically what you need is to make sure you have `pbr` installed.

If you had it already, reinstalling might help

1. `pip uninstall pbr`
2. `pip install pbr`

Comment: I found a solution, pbr is correctly installed. I think the problem was due to celery tasks. I have added these imports in my tasks to instantiate VMs and it works now... Even if I don't know exactely why, so if someone got more explaination, I would appreciate ;)
'from novaclient import client
 from keystoneauth1 import loading
 from keystoneauth1 import session'